# What does TJ mean in the Chinese Language?

Tags: translation

[image]

The picture above is 1 example.

Are there other variations of symbols that resemble TJ?

Comment: I thought this question is about Internet slang TJ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole thing is a [行](http://www.zdic.net/z/23/js/884C.htm) character.

pronunciation:
háng 　ㄏㄤˊ
or
xíng 　ㄒㄧㄥˊ

háng xíng:
to sail,
to fly,
to navigate.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: The picture you gave shows only one Chinese word, 行. It is not TJ.

Comment: The question is about the meaning and variation.

Comment: The symbols are not translating in your answer and could I have a definition?

Comment: Please click the link.

Answer (score 0):

行，读作xíng或者háng如果偏旁写得离得太远的话会变成彳chì    亍chù